# Regex doesn't validate for just one single character

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex:

```
^[\w\-]+([\.\w\s\-]+)*[^\s\.]$
```

...works fine validating strings like this:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc
a . b . d
a_b.c
a-b.c d.e
```

The string should start with one or more characters `\w` or `minus` and can contain 0-n `dots`, `\w` or `spaces`. At the end there should not be any `space` nor `dot`.

The only problem is it doesn't recognize *just one single characters* as valid.
However two characters e.g. `aa`, `a a`, `--`, a_` are recognized.

*Q: how to change the regex to recognize one letter as valid?*

Comment: I have a feeling there's an XY here. What format are you trying to validate?

Comment: In case you don't recognise the problem, it might help you recognise it if you remove the middle section: `^[\w\-]+[^\s\.]$`. You're saying a word character, then something that is not a space or a dot, resulting in a two character minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to impose those restrictions:

```
^(?=[\w-])(?!.*[\s.]$)[.\w\s-]+$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZ4nO1/2)

Since the lookaheads `(?!.*[\s.]$)` and `(?=[\w-])` do not consume characters, the `[.\w\s-]+` subpattern will be able to match just 1 character strings.

The `(?!.*[\s.]$)` checks if the string (without newline symbol, otherwise, replace `.` with `[\s\S]`) ends DOES NOT end with a whitespace or `.`.

The `(?=[\w-])` after `^` checks (once, at the beginning of the string) if a string starts with `-` or a word character.

Comment: Yes that works! Will the ```lookarounds``` work in java script?

Comment: Lookaheads are supported in full by JS ES5 regex engine.

Comment: One more problem :). How to change the regex if the string ```a..a``` should not be valid? So there must be some character between the dots.

Comment: Hmm you are awesome :). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To change the regex to recognize one letter as valid, add a `*` at the end like the example given below.

```
^[\w\-]+([\.\w\s\-]+)*[^\s\.]*$
```

The `[^\s\.]`, the last part is not having any `+` or `*`, your regex needs atleast 2 character to match.

If you add `*` to it, it will match a character.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem because then e.g. this ```a.a.a.``` will be valid. But it should not be because it ends with a ```.```.

Comment: This accepts strings with `.` at the end because of the `*` between `]` and `$` in `[^\s\.]*$`. It makes this `[^\s.]` optional.